# How to assigh the rest of row to a single column in R

Tags: r

Suppose we have this file *someFile* with content:

```
date time data
2015-02-28 09:00:00,173 Some data here
2015-02-28 09:10:00,251 Anoter data here
```

I consider to use read.table

```
read.table("someFile", header=T, sep=" ")
```

I have no idea how to assign the end of row ("Some data here" string) to single column

Answer (score 1):

You could read the file using `readLines`, replace the space before the string with `,` and then try with `read.table`

```
dat1 <- read.table(text=sub('(?<=\\d) (?=[A-Za-z])', ',',
  lines[-1], perl=TRUE), header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",")
colnames(dat1) <-  c('datetime', 'Val', 'Col2')
dat1
#             datetime Val             Col2
#1 2015-02-28 09:00:00 173   Some data here
#2 2015-02-28 09:10:00 251 Anoter data here
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines('SomeFile.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

As your delimiters are not consistent (you have "," and " " delimiters) you'll have to do it in (at least) two times. There are several options but this is in my view the most adaptable and readable one:

1) import the whole file as a list of character strings:

```
   datRaw <- readLines("someFile")[[1]]
```

2) parse it, defining the format by hand.

```
   Parser <- function(line){
                        initSplit <- strsplit(line,"[ ,]")[[1]]
                        firstCol <- initSplit[1]
                        sndCol <- initSplit[2]
                        thirdCol <- strsplit(line,",")[[1]][2]
                        return(c(firstCol,sndCol,thirdCol))
                     }   
   dat <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(datRaw[-1],Parser)))
   names(dat) <- strsplit(datRaw[1]," ")[[1]]


    dat
                                                    date     time
     2015-02-28 09:00:00,173 Some data here   2015-02-28 09:00:00
     2015-02-28 09:10:00,251 Anoter data here 2015-02-28 09:10:00
                                                              data
     2015-02-28 09:00:00,173 Some data here     173 Some data here
     2015-02-28 09:10:00,251 Anoter data here 251 Anoter data here
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, it looks like your 'data' column is using spaces (as it is a string). If you want to support this, you will need to change your separator to something else, like a comma:

```
date,time,number,data
2015-02-28,09:00:00,173,Some data here
2015-02-28,09:10:00,251,Another data here
```

...and:

```
> read.table(someFile, header=T, sep=",")
```

Now it reads correctly.

You can read specific columns using `$column` and utilise `as.vector` to get your 'data' column as a vector:

```
> mydata <- as.vector(read.table(someFile, header=TRUE, sep=",")$data)
> mydata
[1] "Some data here"    "Another data here"
> mydata[1]
[1] "Some data here"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. The file is too large to edit. But I see there is no _justEasy_ way to achieve my goal